# Are Hasura triggers being invoked only if I alter through graphql endpoints?

Tags: javascript, graphql, hasura

I'm scoping a feature and I want to know if Hasura creates native Postgress triggers?

I've actually had another database connection in my app and I wonder if the triggers are being invoked if I alter tables through another library like Knex?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasura Event Triggers use native Postgres triggers underneath. Hence, you would be able to generate events via any client. See: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/blob/master/event-triggers.md